# How do I read multiple lines of input through a pipe?

Tags: c, pipe

Alright, so I am having a problem with transferring input from a simple shell through pipes from a parent process to a child process that has been execlp'd into a logging program. The program in the child process is supposed to print the input that it receives into a file, but I cannot figure out how to pass it an input string, let it process that input string, and then have it wait for another one. I figure that I need to have a read function call somewhere in the child, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Thoughts?

http://pastebin.com/pmU7viNd
(The logger-related part of the simple shell code)

http://pastebin.com/AnkxDdUK
(The code of the logger itself)

Comment: first issue: without seeing how you've actually invoked these commands, we can't know if stdin is redirected properly for the logger. second issue: you're not giving us what the problem actually is. "omg it no work" is not a specific-enough problem statement.